# Detect button click with selenium-wire in python

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I want to take a full screenshot of a web page and save the file in png format after the submit button has been clicked. How can this be done using selenium-wire in python?

I tried the following but the screenshot is not saved although a popup with the message "taking screenshot!!" gets displayed.

```
    html2canvas = """
    var s = window.document.createElement('script');
    s.src = 'https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.min.js';
    window.document.head.appendChild(s);
    """
    
    driver.execute_script(html2canvas)

    script = """
        btn = document.getElementById("input_2")
        btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
        alert('taking screenshot!!');
         // creating canvas of element using html2canvas
          html2canvas(srcElement).then(canvas => {
            // adding canvas/screenshot to the body
            if(btn.id === "take-src-only") {
              return document.body.appendChild(canvas);
            }
            // downloading canvas/screenshot
            const a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = canvas.toDataURL();
            a.download = "fullscreenshot.png";
            a.click();
          });
        });
    """

    driver.execute_script(script)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should check the document https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/interactions/windows/#takeelementscreenshot

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("http://www.example.com")

ele = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h1')
input2 = driver.find_element(By.ID, 'input_2')
    # Returns and base64 encoded string into image
input2.click()
ele.screenshot('./image.png')

#or 
driver.save_screenshot('./image.png')

driver.quit()
```